# Type-dependant implicit cast when calling a method

Tags: scala

What is the scala compiler doing here?

```
def f[A](x: A): A = {
  x
}

f(1,2,3)
```

`res0: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)`

I'm not asking `x` to be a variadic argument. However the compiler seems to be casting the argument list to a product type.

If I specify the type, eg

```
def f(x: Int): Int = {
  x
}
```

and then try to call

```
f(1,2,3)
```

The compiler argues that `too many arguments (3) for method f`

Shouldn't then it say `Expected Int and found (Int, Int, Int)`?

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler infers the type `A` to be `Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]` a.k.a. `(Int, Int, Int)`. It provides syntactic facilities that turn `f(1,2,3)` into `f((1,2,3))`.

Comment: In the second case it doesn't do it, so the casting is depedent on the function type.

Comment: @raul: Yes, the Scala compiler have all sorts of rules when it comes to function/method application, overloading, type inference etc. This is one of the messier areas of Scala. Things will become even more complicated in [Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/auto-parameter-tupling.html).